# Was the Ice King Dreaming too?

Tags: adventure-time, dreams

In King Worm we see that...King Worm has trapped Finn and Jake in their dreams. In their dreams, if they aren't careful they might summon their worst fear.

Along the way they find the Ice King, being chased by a Giant Penguin Monster

> I really did it this time! They're loose and they're coming for us!

[image]

<sub>I'll put this here, just to scar you for life</sub>

No one else they encounter in the dream is able to summon their fears.

Does this mean that the Ice King is/was dreaming too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likley not. Since Finn and Jake don't really like the Ice King, they imagined him being chase by a monster. All the other people weren't able to summon their fears, yes, but that's because I guess they don't really have a problem with them. And if Finn and Jake were able to get rid of their fears, then why didn't the Ice King get rid of the penguin monster? Because he wasn't dreaming. Awesome episode by the way!